# Is this a sensitivity?

Tags: sensitivity-specificity

There are test A and test B. 
I want to show a ratio of test A positive among all test positive(test A positive or test B positive).
Can I call the ratio as sensitivity?
Or is it safe to call as ratio?
I'm wondering because the specificity always becomes 100%.

If someone knows the reference like this case, please tell me. 
I repect any suggestion and I highly appreciate any perspective .

Thank you for the time to consider the thread.

Comment: Sensitivity depends on knowing the true state so unless test B defines that I think the answer is no. Can you perhaps expand a bit on your data set-up?

Comment: My data set is based from 96 patients. The number of test A positive & test B positive are 11 patients and 19 patients, respectively. No. of both test A &B positive is 9 patients.

Comment: So, Sensitivity of test A in the prediction of test A or B positive is calculated as 11/21=0.524 Sensitivity of test B in the prediction of test A or B positive is calculated as 19/21=0.905  However, specificity of test A is 75/75=1.00   Because the target of prediction is test A itself. Can I use sensitivity of my data?   Thank you for your consideration!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you have defined is sensitivity

Sensitivity, Specificity, Precision and Recall are terms derived from the confusion Matrix (http://www.dataschool.io/simple-guide-to-confusion-matrix-terminology/) .
[image]

Sensitivity and Recall are actually the same thing. The formal definition from the confusion matrix is 
$Sensitivity = Recall = (True Positivies)/(True Positives + False Negatives)$

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! I didn't know the word Recall and Precision.